# Apply 3D mask to 3D mask, background is white

Tags: background, binary, mask, image-segmentation

I try to apply a binary mask on a 3D image by multiplying them. It, however, returns an image with a white background, rather than black (what I would expect since the binary mask is 0 and 1, where all of the background pixels equal 0).

First I load the 3D scan/image (.nii.gz) and mask (.nii.gz) with nibabel, using:

```
scan = nib.load(path_to_scan).getfdata()
mask = nib.load(path_to_mask).getfdata()
```

Then I use:

```
masked_scan = scan*mask
```

Below visualized that when applying another mask, the background is darker..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3iDK.jpg)

Below visualized what they look like in 3D slicer as volume.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBsOK.jpg)

What am I missing? Aim is to have a black background...

I also tried np.where(mask==1, scan, mask*scan)